# Aggregated columns return zero

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to aggregate statistics for each app in the table `apps`

I have the following query, but for some reason all the results return `0`

```
select
    a.id,
    'support' as domain,
    'summary' as type,
    90 as interval,
    json_build_object(
        'new', count(new),
        'closed', count(closed_c),
        'reply_rate', count(reply_rate),
        'median_response', max(median_response.response_time)
    ) as data
from apps a
full join (
    SELECT * from conversations c
    WHERE c.started_at::date > (current_date - (90  || ' days')::interval)::date
) as new on new.app_id = a.id
full join (
    SELECT * from conversations c
    WHERE c.closed_at::date > (current_date - (90  || ' days')::interval)::date
) as closed_c on closed_c.app_id = a.id
full join (
    SELECT * from conversations c
    WHERE c.started_at::date > (current_date - (90  || ' days')::interval)::date AND c.first_response_at is not null
) as reply_rate on reply_rate.app_id = a.id
full join (
    SELECT c.app_id, extract(epoch from (c.first_response_at - c.started_at)) as response_time, ntile(2) OVER (ORDER BY (c.first_response_at - c.started_at)) AS bucket FROM conversations c
    WHERE c.started_at::date > (current_date - (90  || ' days')::interval)::date AND c.first_response_at is not null
) as median_response on median_response.app_id = a.id
where a.test = false
group by a.id
```

Comment: Does the `max(median_response.response_time)` also return 0? Are you getting values for `a.id`? Do you get records for the subqueries? Are they joined properly? Do the aggregations work outside of the `json_build_object()`? What if you change to `Count(new.*)` instead of `Count(new)`?

Comment: That one returns `null`. I am getting values for `a.id`. The subqueries should return records? They work outside. Doesnt change anything

Comment: The aggregation formulas work outside of the `json_build_object()`? That really narrows things down!

Comment: They doesnt work outside either

Comment: Ah! OK. So all of my thoughts for troubleshooting have turned up empty. Darn.

Comment: Do you get values from the derived tables if you remove the aggregation and group by? It may help if you can see the results before postgres aggregates.

Comment: Nope you're right, they dont appear even before the aggreate

Comment: That suggests that your joins aren't appropriate for your data. Since you are doing FULL OUTER JOINs then there are no `a.id` that match with each of these tables.

Comment: I don't get why you do the `median_response` Select, currently it's useless. You calculate a `bucket`, but never use it, this is a `max` but not a `median`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell exactly why everything is zero, but

#1: `full join` should be replaced by `left join` (due to the `where a.test = false`)

#2: as you access the same table four times with different conditions this can be probably replaced by a single Select using conditional aggregation.

Check if this returns the correct counts and then Left Join it to `apps`.

```
select
    app_id,
    sum(new),
    sum(closed_c),
    sum(reply_rate),
    max(case when bucket = 1 then response_time end)
from
 (
    SELECT app_id,

       1 as new,

       case when c.closed_at::date > (current_date - (90  || ' days')::interval)::date then 1 else 0 end as closed_c,

       case when c.first_response_at is not null then 1 else 0 end as reply_rate,

       extract(epoch from (c.first_response_at - c.started_at)) as response_time, 

       ntile(2) OVER (ORDER BY (c.first_response_at - c.started_at)) AS bucket
    FROM conversations c
    -- assuming that closed_at is always after started_at
    WHERE c.started_at::date > (current_date - (90  || ' days')::interval)::date 
 ) as dt
group by app_id
```

Comment: This is almost correct, only problem is that it doesnt return `apps` which does not hvae any started conversations in the last 90 days. It should return the app id for these, but then just have zeros in the summary

Comment: @Tarlen: That's why you need to `left join` to `apps` and then use `coalesce(..., 0)` to get the zero.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, you don't use any joins in the above?

Comment: @Tarlen: Yes, you need to add a `left join` to `apps` and then your `json_build_object`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing so many joins when you don't use not a single column from those tables?

If you just need to count, you can do just like that:

```
select
    a.id,
    'support' as domain,
    'summary' as type,
    90 as interval,
    json_build_object(
        'new',              (SELECT count(*)                                                      from conversations c WHERE c.app_id = a.id and c.started_at::date  > current_date - 90),
        'closed',           (SELECT count(*)                                                      from conversations c WHERE c.app_id = a.id and c.closed_at::date   > current_date - 90),
        'reply_rate',       (SELECT count(*)                                                      from conversations c WHERE c.app_id = a.id and c.started_at::date  > current_date - 90 and c.first_response_at is not null),
        'median_response',  (SELECT max(extract(epoch from (c.first_response_at - c.started_at))) from conversations c WHERE c.app_id = a.id and c.started_at::date  > current_date - 90 and c.first_response_at is not null)
    ) as data
from apps a
where a.test = false
```

Also, why are you using interval to add/subtract days into a `date` type?

You could just do `current_date - 90`.

I recommend you create some indexes in `conversations` too:

```
create index i_conversations_started_at on conversations (id, started_at::date); 
create index i_conversations_closed_at on conversations (id, closed_at::date);
```

Comment: Although this looks cleaner, it's about 10x times as slow, and still doesnt solve the problem with zero values

Comment: if it is slower, you should create correct indexes.

Comment: And what problem with 0 values?